# Rails code works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Anyone have any reason why this line would work locally but Heroku would throw an error?

```
where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
```

Cheers!

Comment: Accept rate noted. Ha. And this was the error: `NoMethodError (undefined method `name=' for #<User:0x00000002f175a0>):
2012-07-19T05:51:19+00:00 app[web.1]: app/models/user.rb:17:in `block in from_omniauth'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have forgotten to do a `heroku run rake db:migrate`.